# run a script PHP from Windows command line without opening any browser

Tags: php, windows-console

i want to run a script PHP (example : `http://localhost/project/test.php`) from the command line without opening any browser.
i use the command :

```
START  http://localhost/projetc/test.php
```

but this command opens a browser

do you have any solutions?

Comment: are you really going to run PHP on **MS DOS**? don't you mean "command prompt" maybe?

Comment: i want to run it from a file .bat

Answer (score 2):

Find the path for your php.exe, and run it like this (make sure your run CMD.exe as an administrator):

```
C:\PHP5\php.exe -f "C:\PHP Scripts\script.php"
```

Refer to manual: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php

Answer (score 1):

path/to/php.exe path/to/script.php

Example if you're using xampp:

C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\scripts\script.php